# undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass , NoMethodError in Users#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three models: user, profile, subscription
from the user's index view I can access the profiles table, but I can't access the subscriptions table.
these are the relationships in the model:

```
    class User < ApplicationRecord
      
      has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
      has_one :suscription, dependent: :destroy
      
    
      after_create :set_profile
    
      def set_profile
           self.profile = Profile.create()  
      end      
      
      after_create :set_suscription
    
      def set_suscription
           self.suscription = Suscription.create()  
      end  
    
    end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :user
  
end

class Suscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  enum status: {
    free:     0,
    premium:  1
  }
end
```

I can perfectly access:

```
<%= user.profile.bio%>
```

but I can't access:

```
<%= user.suscription.created_at%>
```

Comment: Hm, these both should suffer from the same problem. Maybe something else creates a profile that is properly linked (but not a subscription). Try `create_profile!` instead of `self.profile = Profile.create()`

Comment: Could you show the error message please?

Comment: First, you've got a typo in the problem line (you need 'su**b**scription').
Second, what happens if you try `Subscription.first.created_at`? That should show that the model exists in the form you expect!

Comment: everything works perfect until I include this line:  <%= user.suscription.created_at%>

Comment: there is a typo, but it is written like this everywhere and it should work.

Comment: I already found the error, it was because I had created users and that is why the subscrption method was unknown. Greetings and thanks for answering